# Pattern for "column total" of an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am looking for a pattern to get the totals for each n-th item of arrays. Conceptually this would be like getting column totals of a data table.

```
var dataRows = [
  [10, 11, 12, 13],
  [20, 21, 22, 23],
  [30, 31, 32, 33]
]
// The outcome should be:
// [ 60, 63, 66, 69]
```

I had some equivalent Python code on the server side, but decided it should be handled client side, thus in javascript. Here is the equivalent Python code:

```
[sum(i) for i in zip(*data_rows)]
```

How would you go about writing this? I am sure the code will be longer without zip, unpack and list comprehension, but can it be done elegantly? Also are there libraries that extend the core library of JS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just iterate over your arrays:

```js
var dataRows = [
  [10, 11, 12, 13],
  [20, 21, 22, 23],
  [30, 31, 32, 33]
]

var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < dataRows.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < dataRows[i].length; j++){
        result[j] = (result[j] || 0) + dataRows[i][j];
    } // ^ Add the current value to the proper position of `result`.
}

alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

As for the second part of your question:
There are libraries that add a lot of array manipulation functions to JS. Take a look at [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/), for example.

Comment: Not sure about `result[j] + dataRows[i][j] || dataRows[i][j];`. If the interim total comes to zero (i.e. `result[j] + dataRows[i][j] == 0`), you'll assign `dataRows[i][j]`.

Comment: Thanks for this. The solution I envisioned would introduce some extra variables, but the smart part is that you write the values to the result array. I thought I was not looking for some nested iteration, but the way you code: I guess I do. Accepted as elegant :)

Comment: @RobG: I changed that line a little. Can you provide some data that would cause issues? I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at, properly.

Comment: @RobG: There is no harm in that, is there?

Comment: If `result[j] + dataRows[i][j]` evaluates to zero, then `dataRows[i][j]` will be assigned to `result[j]` rather than zero. I presume you are testing if `result[j]` exists yet and assigning `dataRows[i][j]` if it doesn't. What you have now does the job, more explicit would be something like: `result[j] = (j in result? result[j] : 0) + dataRows[i][j]`.

Answer (score 6):

Play with ES5 array methods:

```
var dataRows = [
  [10, 11, 12, 13],
  [20, 21, 22, 23],
  [30, 31, 32, 33]
];

dataRows.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.map(function(el, i) {
    return el + b[i];
  });
});
// [60, 63, 66, 69]
```

This is attempt to give a clue, so I didn't deal with error handling thing.

Comment: yep i was 2 secs away from posting the same

Comment: this is the best answer

Comment: Just keep in mind that these methods (`map`/`reduce`) aren't supported by IE versions older than 9. And it breaks if the sub-arrays don't all have the same length. (Try: `var dataRows=[[10,5],[20]];`)

Comment: @Cerbrus Yep, I addressed that in front of my answer. It's just giving a clue of possible solution to the OP.

Comment: I guess this answer is closer to what I anticipated. On the other hand the Hellhound's answer below seems to be closer the idiomatic javascript that most people are used to. Therefore potentially more helpful. Leaving that as accepted answer...

Comment: Yea, If you can trust the source of your data, and you don't have to worry about supporting ancient browsers, this is probably how I'd implement it.